# How to automatically restart apache on conf file changes

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring

I'm doing testing with apache editing the 000-defualt.conf file very often on vim, saving, and next running `service apache2 restart`.

What options do I've to automatically restart apache when a change to that file is made?

Comment: You may be able to use inotify in a manor similar to the method in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264238/restart-process-on-file-change-in-linux)

Comment: Consider running *reload* action instead of *restart*. This takes less time and doesn't break existing connections. Only (un)loading modules needs full restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [inotifywait](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) (install your distribution's `inotify-tools` package):

`while inotifywait -e close_write 000-defualt.conf; do service apache2 restart; done`